# Setting After Effects timeline markers using ExtendScript

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

The [After Effects scripting guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) makes it clear how to set layer markers but I have yet to find a way to set timeline markers.

The code for setting a layer marker is as follows:

```
var myMarker = new MarkerValue("Fade Up");
myLayer.property("Marker").setValueAtTime(2, myMarker);
```

I would like to add a marker to the timeline but calling the same function on an item returns undefined.

```
app.project.item[i].property("Marker").setValueAtTime(2, myMarker);
```

How can I access timeline markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not officially supported to grab timeline comp markers via AE's Scripting API, but it is possible via scripting.  Check out Paul Tuersley's solution on this thread at the Adobe forums.  I implemented it and it's working fine.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4747367#4747367

Comment: Yes, that works to access existing markers, but the request was for "a way to set timeline markers"

Comment: true, but I just wanted to point the OP to a solution that at least got him half way there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad news, but timeline (comp) markers are not accessible with ExtendScript, only layer markers. This may change with the next major update to AE, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No longer true since 2014. Markers can be accessed with `comp.markerProperty`.